# TSQL - Exclusion Condition

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to build a SQL script that will produce a list of fields for forward-conversion.  By this i mean when the application was initially deployed, we had to migrate old data into the new database, as such the old data does not comply with the new standard.  I didnt do the migration, only cleaning it up.

Design:

```
select * from tblclient
where LEN(clientmatter) <> 11
    and clientmatter not in (select * from tblclient
                where ISNUMERIC(clientmatter) <> 1)
```

I know syntactically this will not work but the design should lend a hand on what i am trying to do.

The derived table inside the condition will be used with this secondary table in a Union All.  I am trying to exclude the non-numeric results from the length problem results so i can get a complete set of information with both conditions.

Tested Design:

```
select 'non-numeric', clientmatter
from tblclient
where ISNUMERIC(clientmatter) <> 1
UNION ALL
select 'length problem', clientmatter
from tblclient
where LEN(clientmatter) <> 11
```

Tried this but i get duplication.  I remember doing a script where i union'ed two queries but only produced one result but can remember how i did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT clientmatter,
       CASE
         WHEN LEN(clientmatter) <> 11 THEN 'length problem'
       END,
       CASE
         WHEN ISNUMERIC(clientmatter) <> 1 THEN 'non-numeric'
       END
FROM   tblclient
WHERE  ISNUMERIC(clientmatter) <> 1
        OR LEN(clientmatter) <> 11
```

Comment: This worked....guess i was overthinking the logic.....The Length and Non-Numeric constants were just a debugging step.  Ended up adding the Length and IsNumeric values as columns for testing.  The end-result is that the clientmatter value will be the only field in the resulting table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select 'non-numeric', clientmatter
from tblclient
where ISNUMERIC(clientmatter) <> 1 and LEN(clientmatter)=11
UNION ALL
select 'length problem', clientmatter
from tblclient
where LEN(clientmatter) <> 11 and IsNumeric(clientMatter)=1
UNION ALL
select 'both problems', clientmatter
from tblclient
where LEN(clientmatter) <> 11 and IsNumeric(clientMatter)=0
```